# Codeigniter text area validation rule doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to validate text area in codeigniter

code in view

```
 Write the best two hoppy you pratise
  <?php   $user=" ";  ?>
  <form action= "<?php echo base_url('log_c/save_hoppy/ ' .$user ); ?>" method="post" >
  <?php echo form_error('hoppy'); ?>
 <textarea name="hoppy" cols="20"  rows="2"> 
      <?php echo set_value('hoppy'); ?> 
</textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value=" Save ">

</form>
```

and this code in controller

```
public function save_hoppy($user)
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hoppy', 'Hoppy', 'required|max_length[40]');

    echo"after validation".$user."<br>";
    $hoppy = $this->input->post('hoppy');
    echo"<br>this hoppy".$hoppy;


}
```

But this validation doesn't work
.the population text area work   please any one help me

Comment: What doesn't work? What's your test case?

Comment: I want limit the amount of text area to be at most 40 character

Comment: this code doesn't limit the text area by validation rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove above text area and paste Codeigniter form input

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'hoppy',
    'id'          => 'hoppy',
    'rows'        => '2',
    'cols'        => '20',
    'maxlength'        => '40'
);

echo form_textarea($data);
```

Comment: i try form_text area ()  but the same problem

Comment: add this 'maxlength'        => '40' in above array

Comment: i want to put set value how i write it ?

Comment: ohhh  .it works without using validation rule   thank you very much

Comment: @A.Nabil happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution

```
<textarea name="description"> 
<?php echo set_value('description'); ?> 
</textarea>
```